# GridView getView() in position 0 called more than three time

Tags: gridview

`GridView` the `getView()` called more than three time at position 0 due to I don't have enough reputation so I can't upload the picture. Look forward to reply!

Code:

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{ 
    LogUtils.i(position + ""); 
    CalendarItem item = (CalendarItem)convertView; 
    if (item == null) 
    { 
        item = new CalendarItem(context, null); calItemSp.put(position, item);  
        item.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewTransformUtil.layoutHeigt(context, 60))); 
        item.setOnCalendarItemListener(onCalendarItemListener); 
    }
```

Comment: Your post does not contain enough information to provide an answer. Edit your post to include relevant code.